# Nullity and an Isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm working on some introductory proofs in linear algebra, and I think that
I could use some help on this particular problem. I want to prove that a
linear surjective map $T: R \rightarrow W$ is an isomorphism if and only if
its nullity is zero.

Essentially, what I need to do is show that linear transformation will be
injective if and only if its kernel is 0. Consider the case where $T$ is
injective. I know that there is one vector in $R$ that maps to the zero
vector in $W$, but why must that necessarily mean that that such a vector is
the $0$ vector in $R$? I think I could use help with this part of the
proof. In the case where we assume that the kernel is 0, we know that only
the $O$ vector in $R$ is the only vector that maps to the $0$ vector in $R$,
but I can't seem to see how this would imply that the rest of the values
in $W$ that are mapped onto are mapped 1-to-1. I guess I could use some
clarification on the path to take on both of these directions.

Comment: For the first direction, assume that there are two vectors in $R$ which map to the same element, and use linearity of $T$ and the fact that the kernel is $0$ to show that they must be the same. For the other direction, by linearity $0$ is mapped to $0$, and you can use injectivity together with linearity to show that no other element can be mapped to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use linearity of $T$.

> Suppose $\ker T = \{0\}$, then consider $T(x) = T(y)$ for any $x,y \in R$. Then $$T(x) = T(y) \implies T(x) - T(y) = 0 \implies T(x-y) = 0 \implies x-y = 0 \implies x= y$$
>  Thus $T$ is injective. 
> On the other hand, if $T$ is injective and $x$ is any element in $\ker T$ then $$T (x) = 0  = T(0) \implies x = 0$$
>  Thus $\ker T$ has only $0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Try to prove that *any* linear transformation sends $0$ to $0$ (that is, if $T: V\rightarrow W$ is linear, then $T(0_V)=0_W$). To do this, use the fact that part of the definition of linearity is that for all $a, b$ in the domain of $T$,  $$T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b).$$ Do you see how to use this to get what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fact that the map is *linear* (without that hypothesis the result would not be true). If $v,v'\in R$ would be distinct vectors with $T(v)=T(v')$, what would $T(v-v')$ be?